# How to name parameters for a function in a method signature in scala?

Tags: scala

```
def downloadResultsPage(onPageDownload: (List[String], Boolean) => Unit) {
    body here...
}
```

In this example onPageDownload is the closure that will be called when the page is completed.  To make the code self-document better, I'd really like to be able to have something like this:

```
(onPageDownload: (results: List[String], finished: Boolean) => Unit)
```

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: write `CaseClass => Unit` where `CaseClass` is `case class CaseClass(results: List[String], finished: Boolean)`

Answer (score 2):

you can create type alias like `type DownloadCompletedHook = (List[String], Boolean) => Unit` or you can create trait and then implicitly convert if you wish your functions to this trait:

```
trait DownloadCompletedHook extends ((List[String], Boolean) => Unit) {
  def apply(results: List[String], finished: Boolean): Unit
}

implicit def funToTrait(f: (List[String], Boolean) => Unit): DownloadCompletedHook = new DownloadCompletedHook {
  def apply(results: List[String], finished: Boolean): Unit = f(results, finished)
}
```

and more simple way (but less semantic i think) is to group `results: List[String], finished: Boolean` into case class